# Using custom property in a Template

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a custom field, which extends `Ext.form.field.Text`. My new field uses custom template, like so:

```
fieldSubTpl: [
    '<div class="uk-margin-medium-bottom"><div class="md-input-wrapper"><label for="{id}">{label}</label><input class="md-input" id="{id}" name="{name}" type="text" value="{value}" /><span class="md-input-bar "></span></div></div>',{
    compiled: true}
],
```

The problem is with this `{label}` property inside the template. If I check it in initComponent method like so:

```
...
initComponent: function() {
   console.log(this.label); // prints out some value
},
...
```

I see some value in the console. So, this property exists and the component sees it, however, I do not know how can I use it inside the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `<label>` and `<input>` tags are rendered separately.

Label is rendered using `Labelable` [mixin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.Labelable.html#cfg-labelableRenderTpl). You can change it's render template using config `labelableRenderTpl`.

In case you still want to use `fieldSubTpl` to render everything at once, you should extend [`getSubTplData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Text.js.html#Ext.form.field.Text-method-getSubTplData) method of the component and append `label` value to returned object. This object will be passed to the `fieldSubTpl` template for render.

UPD. Example fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ui1

Comment: Thanks! I guess, I need to clarify, that I'm not using modern theme, so in my case `label` is just a custom property. It could be "property1" or some other arbitrary property. As for `getSubTplData`, it would be great if you could elaborate a liitle bit on this topic and show some code snippets